# How to set dynamical link in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I use Angular 2 RC.4 and new Router (since RC.2).
I know `[routerLink]` directive provides to generate URL, but how to set links using parameters got from API server?

```
// Getting errors because self is undefined...
<a [routerLink]="['/users', 'edit', self.id]">Update Profile</a>

// Then, using Safe Navigation Operator but getting errors...
<a [routerLink]="['/users', 'edit', self?.id]">Update Profile</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're populating the info you want on your component.

```
@Component({
   selector: 'foo',
   template: `
      <a [routerLink]="['/users', 'edit', id]">Update Profile<a>
   `
})
export class FooComponent {
   id: number;
   constructor () {
       myHttpCall().then((user) => { this.id = user.id });
   }
}
```

You can only access information in the template that is on `this`.

Comment: hmmm. When I appended the code `this.id = this.user.id`, it does work I expected to. But it's dirty code... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`<a [routerLink]="['/users', 'edit', self?.id]">Update Profile</a>` - This will not give errors if you have a self variable in your component. Since you are accessing this with ? - I can assume that self is populated asynchronously. This will work once you have the data. But if user clicks before data load, then it is bound to fail.

You can use `*ngIf` and show the link when data is available
If data is loaded from API and you are using Observables then you can do something like `(self | async)?.id` - but again link will be incorrect unless it is loaded
Finally, I think you can use something like this to be safe
In template
```

```
<button (click)="gotoUpdate()">Update Profile</button>
```

`And in component`

```
gotoUpdate() {
  if(self) {
    this.router.navigate(['/users', 'edit', self.id]);
  }
}
```

```

In the above approach as well, you need to ensure button is not clicked until data is available, because of if condition buttong click wont do anything until you have data

Comment: I apologize to you for the lack of information. The component will get user data using XHR in its `constructor()` , when the component is activated. So Safe Navigation Operator does work in elements (e.g. `div {{user?.id}}` ), but does not work in `[routerLink]` directive.